# Machine Learning with JSON Dataset

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a collection of JSON documents with labels. I want to train a classifier taking into account the k/v pairs of each JSON doc. Many of the values are not numerical, but rather a string.

Is there a way to process the k/v pairs directly in their native formate rather than converting all the values into a matching integer through a data pipeline?

My goal is to eventually be able to take the native JSON response from an application's API and to use the trained classifier to identify what kind of document it is.

Bag of words doesn't really work in this approach because the majority of the words are going to be identical between records.

Comment: You have tagged scikit-learn, so I assume you want to work in it. No, there is no way in scikit to work directly with KV pairs. There is DictVectorizer available which will convert your data to appropriate one

Comment: This question might be better suited for Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you don't insist on using python, you can use the following Julia libraries which are specifically suited for ML on JSONs: https://github.com/pevnak/Mill.jl and https://github.com/pevnak/JsonGrinder.jl